# Why Google Map with padding set lags?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I've set a padding to my Google Map instance to fit the screen with bottom sheet opened:

`map.setPadding(0, 0, 0, sheetViewHeight)`

and it's works great. But when I move or animate the map camera everything is lagging as hell. Map rendering in a few seconds. But when I close the sheet and remove the padding:

`map.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)`

and then move the camera everything is fine. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Then I suspect something may be wrong with `BottomSheet` itself. Kindly make sure there is no heavy running operations on `BottomSheet`. I would say, just trying displaying empty bottom sheet or some static UI and try the same.

Comment: make sure you do not run setPaddings from repeatedly running callback like onGlobalLayout

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with setting padding to the map. A bottom sheet over the map seems to make the map lag for me too. Haven't found a fix for it yet

Comment: Have you found a solution? It seems that I have the same issue